# ingress nginx canary deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, cicd

could you please help me what is wrong with the manifest below deployed in kubernetes.
I expect that 80% of requests goes to nginx1 and 20% to nginx2 but all the traffics goes to nginx2!!!

here is the configmap to replace the default home page of nginx containers.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: nginx-configmap
  namespace: test
data:
  nginx1-content: |
   I'm version v1!
   </html>
  nginx2-content: |
   I'm version v2!
```

hear is the deployment for nginx1.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx1-deployment
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: nginx1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.24.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: nginx-configmap
          items:
          - key: nginx1-content
            path: index.html
```

hear is the service for nginx1.

````
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx1
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80 ```
````

hear is the deployment for nginx2.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx2-deployment
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: nginx2
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.24.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/
          readOnly: true
        
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: nginx-configmap
          items:
          - key: nginx2-content
            path: index.html
```

hear is the service for nginx2.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  namespace: test
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx2
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

At the end, her are my ingress configs

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx2
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: \"true\"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: \"20\"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ehsan.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx2
            port:
              number: 80
---              
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx1
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: \"true\"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: \"80\"  
spec:
  rules:
  - host: ehsan.test.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: nginx1
            port:
              number: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

The point is that I should create different namespaces one for nginx1 and another for nginx2.
the objects name should be the same in both namespaces.
define annotation only for one of the ingress object